# How to make a class interface Require an implementation of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, requires

I simply need to know the "requires" syntax for a C# class interface.  If I have a class like this:

```
public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode
```

How can I make the interface **require** the implementation of IEnumerable?  I think this is very simple and just a syntax thing, but feel free to prove me wrong.

Update:

```
public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode, IEnumerable<ISceneNode>
```

Now I'm confused on where to implement IEnumerable?  I have no concrete class implementation of ISceneNode.  Should I do it in the concrete class implementation of IGroupNode instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode, IEnumerable
```

Just like you did with your other interface.

Comment: Alright now this may seem like a silly question a well, but where should I implement the IEnumerable?

Comment: @DNA_Instant in your implementation (a class the implements your interface) of IGroupNode

Comment: You have to create a new class that implements `IGroupNode`. This will automatically require to implement the interfaces that `IGroupNode` implements.

Comment: Ah okay, that's what I thought.  (I was just making sure it wasn't that I was supposed to do that implementation in ISceneNode, instead.)  The interface concept is very simple but for some reason my brain always overthinks it or finds it confusing.

Comment: @DNA_Instant: maybe an analogy helps. Consider a cookbook: the ingredients are the `interface`, they define what's inside your concrete object. The actual food you prepared is a concrete implementation (`class`) of the earlier ingredients. An interface lists the methods (in our case ingredients) that have to be used in your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode, IEnumerable
```